# PayPal datetime (payment_date) parsing issue

Tags: c#, .net

PayPal sends payment `datetime` like:

> 09%3A37%3A22+Nov+18%2C+2012+PST

I try to convert it by this code but getting an exception.

Any clue about how to parse it?

Thank you!

```
DateTime paymentDate;
DateTime.TryParse(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(r["payment_date"]), out paymentDate);
n.PaymentDate = paymentDate; // payment_date=09%3A37%3A22+Nov+18%2C+2012+PST
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DateTime paymentDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(r["payment_date"]),
    "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out paymentDate);
```

Comment: +1, the solution is to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` instead of `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`.

Comment: Of course, if there's a possibility that the `CurrentCulture` could have a `TimeSeparator` or `AbbreviatedMonthNames` that differ from the English one (`":"` and `"Jan"`/`"Feb"`/...), do pass the `InvariantCulture` as `provider` instead of `null`.

Comment: Now they seems to have changed it to "PDT" instead of "PST" as in "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT"..

Comment: Paypal sends date sometimes with PST sometime with PDT, therefore this solution is obsolete and **does not work reliably**.
@DHlavaty has the right solution for this problem.

Comment: For the best solution look at Ben's comment.

Answer (score 14):

There are various datetime formats in PayPal's documentation. I use this method to parse it, and convert it to UTC:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tries to parse PayPal formatted date and time and converts it to an UTC.
/// </summary>
public static bool TryParsePaypalDatetimeToUtc(this string paypalDatetime, out DateTime retValue)
{
    DateTime paymentDate;

    // PayPal formats from docs
    string[] formats = new string[] { "HH:mm:ss dd MMM yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss dd MMM yyyy PST", 
                                      "HH:mm:ss dd MMM, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss dd MMM, yyyy PDT", 
                                      "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT" };
    if (false == DateTime.TryParseExact(paypalDatetime, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out paymentDate))
    {
        retValue = DateTime.MinValue;
        return false;
    }

    retValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(paymentDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you use `paypalDatetime.Replace("PST", "-08:00").Replace("PDT", "-07:00")` as your input argument to the TryParseExact method then you could reduce the number of formats to 3 (replacing the PDT and PST with zzz).  Then you could simple set `retValue = paymentDate.ToUniversalTime();`.