# Payment Date as UTC

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am programming the back end of my website (ASP.Net C# framework 4.0).  I am listening for results using my PayPal IPN listener, which will update my back-end database.

When a payment is made I would like to record the payment date.  I am having trouble parsing the payment_date parameter that is given to me from the IPN message.  It looks like this:

```
args["payment_date"]: 10:23:05 Dec 02, 2013 PST
```

The following try-parse is always returning a false:

```
DateTime paymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime.TryParse(args["payment_date"], out paymentDate);
```

PST stands for Pacific Standard Time right?  I read that some US states that use PST will switch to PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) at some point in the year.

In my database I would like to store all DateTimes as UTC.  Is there a way that I can ask PayPal to give me the payment date in UTC?  Or do I have to write my own parser?  If so then is there anything else I should watch out for apart from the switch from PST to PDT?

Perhaps you might think I should just use my own server time to record the payment date, but I just thought it would be better to use the date given by PayPal themselves in the actual IPN message.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445510/paypal-datetime-payment-date-parsing-issue

Comment: Nice find @PatrickQuirk - not sure why this did not appear when I looked for it.

Comment: Seems a shame that I can't just ask PayPal to give me the payment date in UTC.  Also according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19004676/340045) PayPal use several date-time formats.  How inconsiderate of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify a custom `DateTime` format that matches what PayPal gives you, and pass that to the `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` method:

```
DateTime paymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
string format = "hh:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy";
DateTime.TryParseExact(args["payment_date"], out paymentDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Parsing the timezone shorthand is not supported in .NET, so per Patrick's comment on my answer, check here for a workaround: [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Comment: Parsing the abbreviations is not supported in .NET, so the "K" formatter won't match.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc for an ugly workaround...

Comment: So since .NET doesn't support timezone shorthand, and according to Patrick's link, how about using `.Replace("PST", "-07:00").Replace("PDT", "-08:00")` (did I get that the right way round?) and adding zzz to the format?

Comment: Just checked and PST is -08:00 and PDT is -07:00.

Comment: You could, but it's overly expensive to do repeated replacements... Each one costs you an O(n) traversal of the string.

Comment: Thanks David, at the moment I don't think my online shop will have to worry about the computational expense of a couple of Replace methods.  The date-time string is fairly short anyway so shouldn't impact too much.  If it starts to become a bottleneck then I will be earning so much that I will be able to afford to pay someone else to do my website for me ;-)

Comment: Exactly. Good mentality. Don't solve problems you don't yet have.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check here:

[How do I convert Paypal's HH:MM:SS DD Mmm(.) YYYY PST/PDT to a C# UTC DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500160/how-do-i-convert-paypals-hhmmss-dd-mmm-yyyy-pst-pdt-to-a-c-sharp-utc-date)

But your format should be in HH:MM:SS DD Mmm(.) YYYY PST/PDT first.